# Simplificar varias funciones en 1 sola

Tags: javascript

tengo la siguiente consulta, ¿como puedo simplificar estas funciones?

```
function popinfo1() {
    let info1 = document.getElementById("info1");
    if (info1.style.display === "" || info1.style.display === "none") {
        info1.style.display = "flex";
    } else {
        info1.style.display = "none";
    }
}
function popinfo2() {
    let info2 = document.getElementById("info2");
    if (info2.style.display === "" || info2.style.display === "none") {
        info2.style.display = "flex";
    } else {
        info2.style.display = "none";
    }
}
function popinfo3() {
    let info3 = document.getElementById("info3");
    if (info3.style.display === "" || info3.style.display === "none") {
        info3.style.display = "flex";
    } else {
        info3.style.display = "none";
    }
}
...
```

En total tengo 17 "popinfo" por lo que ya se imaginarán el súper código que me cargo, de igual forma si me pudieran recomendar fuentes para poder entender un poco más sobre compresión de código estaría genial.

Saludos!

Comment: Estaría bien saber cuando quieres llamar a esas funciones, y que quieres hacer. Si al hacer click en un elemento, ocultarlo y mostrar el resto o que

Comment: Si, tengo unos botones de información y al dar click en ellos se muestra un div con información detallada, es por ello que cada botón tiene un número en específico

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gracias @RuthIsRoot tu código me ayudo a mi requerimiento, como tal no necesitaba ejecutar todos los info si no conforme se iban seleccionando, por lo que solamente quité el for quedando así:

```
function popinfo(a) {
    let info = document.getElementById("info"+a);
    if (info.style.display === "" || info.style.display === "none") {
        info.style.display = "flex";
    } else {
        info.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Podrías utilizar una función que recorra todos tus ID mediante un bucle `for` :

```
function popinfo() {
    for (let i = 1; i <= 17; i++) {
        let info = document.getElementById("info"+i);
        if (info.style.display === "" || info.style.display === "none") {
            info.style.display = "flex";
        } else {
            info.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

Aquí, tal y como comentas, tienes 17 elementos "info". En esta función mediante el bucle `for`, puedes recorrer todos los elementos que necesitas utilizando la variable `i` para gestionar el número.

Comment: En caso de que necesites alguna aclaración o tengas algún problema, comentamelo. Cabe decir, que siempre hay una forma mejor de realizar esta acción ya que si añademos más elementos, tendrás que actualizar el bucle. Esto hace que realmente no sea una función completamente óptima.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías ponerle a cada elemento popinfo una clase con la que indetificar a todos los elementos y luego poder seleccionarlos por esa misma clase. `class="popInfo"`. También en lugar de modificar el atributo style, crear una clase css para ocultarlo y añadir o quitar dicha clase.

El css:

```
.ocultar{
    display: none;
}
```

El javascript

```
const elements = document.getElementsByClassName("popInfo");
for(let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
    const element = elements[i];
    element.addEventListener("click", mostrar);
}


function mostrar(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     e.target.classList.toggle("mostrar");
}
```